# returning the feature data type in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I need to return the data types of each columns. This is my sample pandas dataframe.

```
employee = {'sell' : [0,21,25,13,64,75,564,37,38,92],
       'employ_id' : [123242,15612,16234,12456,123245,32234,1234,1253,127,843],
               'x' : [-82.45,-85.24,-82.12,-85.66,-82.124,-83.122,-83.124,-84.232,-81.22,-86.25],
               'y' : [33.4,33.21,33.11,33.51,33.16,33.167,33.33,33.54,33.25,33.267]}

employee_df = pd.DataFrame(employee)
```

and this is how the output should look like.

```
In [1]: variable_helper(df[['employee_id','sell','x','y']])
Out[1]: {'sell': 'categorical',
         'employee_id': 'ordinal',
         'x': 'numeric',
         'y': 'numeric'}
```

Even though I know how to get the datatype using *.dtypes, it won't return me something like "categorical", "ordinal", etc.
Is there a way to solve this??
Thank you.

Comment: Well how could pandas possibly guess that `sell` is categorical?

Comment: thats what Im saying. I was wondering if this is something I have to define or make another template or something ...:(

Comment: In pandas, I'm not aware of a way. I assume this is a machine learning exercise. If you want sell to be a categorical variable, then instead of defining a dtype as one, use sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder to generate the categories. You can get back the categories using LabelEncoder.classes_ But in sell I don't see any categories you can work with -- all are unique.

Comment: @Yun One way you could guess if it's categorical is if the number of unique values for a column is below a certain threshold of all values... Apart from that though...(and guessing generally isn't good)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I am understanding well, but have you tried to define yourself the dtype of each column? If you want the series "Sell" to be categorical you could do something like [this](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html):

```
s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")
```

Also if you do `employee_df.info()` you can see the dtype of each series.